# boost::asio QNX linker error

Tags: c++, boost-asio, qnx-neutrino

I am new to using boost libraries in QNX platform. I am having trouble with linking the asio library. It throws me undefined reference linker errors in `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops` level. The messages are:

in function `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::call_bind` undefined reference to bind ..

& similar errors for `listen`, `recvmsg`, `accept`, `setsockopt` ..

I got these errors when I include the asio library only as header library( I didn't separately compiled it).

Then I tried to compile the library explicitly by defining `BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION` and including the `<boost/asio/ssl/impl/src.hpp>` once. It throws me more undefined reference errors to the functions defined in socket_ops.hpp.

The errors occurs in `socket_ops.ipp` and I am using boost_1_49 in QNX Neutrino Momentics 6.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you built boost for your platform? Is it in a compatible configuration for your application target?

Asio requires a few other boost libraries (date_time and threading among them if I recall), which must be built prior to use (some libraries are not header only, or they are dependent on libraries that are not header only).

Comment: The problem is solved when I gave the compile switches -lsocket option as in the Linux. thanks for the answer.